# Windows phone AppHub submission, Static validation completed with errors "unknown error 5000"

Tags: windows-phone-7, publish

I tried to publish my application to the windows phone beta marketplace, but when I try to publish it I get a "Static validation completed with errors" with an "Unknown error 5000".

I tried the Marketplace Test Kit in Visual Studio, and all tests are completing without any errors. What can cause this kind of errors ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsphone/2009/deployment" AppPlatformVersion="7.1">
  <App xmlns="" ProductID="{a3ea5c79-71e3-47a8-9fdd-e98e1bd3fa14}" Title="Beat" RuntimeType="Silverlight" Version="1.0.0.0" Genre="apps.normal" Author="Philipp" Description="Sample description" Publisher="Philipp">
    <IconPath IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Images\AppTile.png</IconPath>
    <Capabilities>
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_GAMERSERVICES" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_DEVICE" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_IDENTITY_USER" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MEDIALIB" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_MICROPHONE" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_NETWORKING" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_PUSH_NOTIFICATION" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_SENSORS" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_WEBBROWSERCOMPONENT" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_ISV_CAMERA" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_CONTACTS" />
      <Capability Name="ID_CAP_APPOINTMENTS" />
    </Capabilities>
    <Tasks>
      <DefaultTask Name="_default" NavigationPage="Pages/HomePage.xaml" />
      <ExtendedTask Name="BackgroundTask">
        <BackgroundServiceAgent Specifier="AudioPlayerAgent" Name="BeatBackgroundPlayer" Source="BeatBackgroundPlayer" Type="no.nLink.beat.AudioPlayer" />
      </ExtendedTask>
    </Tasks>
    <Tokens>
      <PrimaryToken TokenID="Beat_appToken" TaskName="_default">
        <TemplateType5>
          <BackgroundImageURI IsRelative="true" IsResource="false">Images\ApplicationIcon.png</BackgroundImageURI>
          <Count>0</Count>
          <Title>Beat mobile</Title>
        </TemplateType5>
      </PrimaryToken>
    </Tokens>
  </App>
</Deployment>
```

Comment: Post the code from the `WMAppManifest.xml` file into your question.

Comment: I think I figured out why it is not working. Since I am programming for the Norwegian market, I set the NeutralResourcesLanguage to Norwegian. 

But this doesn't seem to work, after I specified it to Norwegian Bookmal the unknown error disappeared.

Is there another possible explanation why this works now? Or is it just not working if I use only Norwegian has the NeutralResourceLanguge which would be bad because visual studio has this as an option when choosing it in the "Assembly Information".

Comment: Actually it's because of the images being in a sub-folder, see my answer ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You're having your ApplicationIcon (AppTile.png) and BackgroundImage (ApplicationIcon.png) in a sub-folder, **this is not supported**. They need to be placed in the root!

Also, If you set the `NeutralResourcesLanguage` to `no` you should still have a `Resources.no.resx` represented in your project, otherwise the marketplace language detecting on the AppHub is bound to fail, as they detect available languages based on resource-assembly availability.

Try add a `Resources.no.resx` if you're missing it.

And, more importantly, you listed **all** the capabilities. There's no chance in hell that your application uses all of them, so remove those you don't need. Use the Marketplace Test Kit to find which capabilities you need.

Comment: don't the caps get re-validated and replaced by ingestion anyway?  (But yes, you should only list the capabilities you're actually using)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg180730(v=VS.92).aspx says:  `When you submit an application to the Marketplace, the capabilities of the application are programmatically detected. The application submission process uses Microsoft Intermediate Language (MSIL) code analysis to detect the phone capabilities required by the application. The application submission process replaces the capabilities list, whether it is the auto-generated list or a list that you have modified, with the specific capabilities required for your application...`

Comment: My experience with the AppHub been different. I wouldn't trust it, regardless if it really can detect it.

Comment: Also, capabilities like Front Facing Camera, can't be detected, you'll have to add those yourself. I think by "replaces" probably should been "appends".

Comment: So I managed to get it to the Beta Marketplace, it looks like the I do not need a Resources.no.resx as long as I specify it as Norwegian bookmal, and have the Images in an Image folder is no problem as long as it is not the SplashScreenImage.

Comment: The error you posted is related to having the images in a sub-folder. If they changed the marketplace processing, just be happy.